# Multiple Instances of a table in a web2py form

Tags: database, web2py

Trying to make a poll application in web2py.

**Model**

```
db.define_table('t_query',
    Field('f_content', type='text', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY(),
          label=T('Content')),
    SQLField('is_active',db.auth_user,writable=False,readable=False),
    auth.signature,
    migrate=settings.migrate)

db.define_table('t_option',
    Field('f_ocontent', type='string',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY(),
          label=T('Option')),
    auth.signature,
    migrate=settings.migrate)
```

**Controller**

```
def ask():
    form=SQLFORM.factory(db.t_query,db.t_option,db.t_option)
    if form.process().accepted:
        id = db.t_query.insert(**db.t_query._filter_fields(form.vars))
        form.vars.client=id
        id = db.t_option.insert(**db.t_option._filter_fields(form.vars))
        response.flash='Thanks for filling the form'
        id = db.t_option.insert(**db.t_option._filter_fields(form.vars))
        response.flash='Thanks for the question'
    return dict(form=form)
```

**View**

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}

<h2>Start a Poll</h2>
{{=form}}
```

**Output**
[image: current]

I have tried finding how to ask  SQLFORM to use fields from the same table multiple times in a form.

**This is what I expect:**
[image: gexpectation]

How do I go about it?

Asked the same question on web2py@googlegroups https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py/48tO5ncC2t4

Comment: btw, I see you have two `response.flash` assignments in a row. The 2nd will overwrite the first every time the form is successfully processed since there are no if statements to determine when to send one flash message vs the other... maybe it doesn't matter for your code right now, but thought i'd point it out.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to be able to store a list of strings for a single field. As far as I know, you cannot repeat the same field multiple times (where would the data go in the database? There is only a single field to contain it, so you need to serialize it and jam it in there if you want 0..n values in a single field)

Use this to get multiple strings in a single field:

```
db.define_table(...
  ...
  Field('f_ocontent', 'list:string')
)
```

This will store the data internally as such:

```
|option1val|option2val|option3val|
```

or, if empty:

```
||
```

You can hit enter when you're in an input that has more than 0 chars and it will create a new input.